# "Operation not allowed without an active reactive context" with almost everything in server function

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to get a Shiny app to run and getting this error. I know the usual explanation (accessing `input$foo` or `output$foo` outside a reactive expression). But that doesn't seem to apply in my case. I've moved almost all my logic inside my `shinyServer` function. so my `server.R` looks like:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    parts <- strsplit(input$text, split=" ")
    ok <- c()
    ...
  }
)
```

So there is just the imports outside (and these were working in an earlier version that I stupidly didn't revision). I've narrowed the problem down to the two lines shown in the shinyServer function; the problem doesn't happen with either one of those on its own, but with both I get the crash.

UPDATE: so I figured it out: I thought the function in shinyServer call was a reactive expression but it isn't. I have to in turn wrap its code that accesses input in a call to reactive().

Comment: Hi Graham, which error are you getting

Comment: We need to see a minimal reproducible example that triggers the same error. Are you saying you get the error when your shinyServer function is empty?!? If so, what have you stored in the .Rdata file?

Comment: Updated with a more specific repro case.